# Check if Layered navigation filter is active on Magento

Tags: catalog, layered-navigation, filter

I'm having trouble **identifying the catalog pages that are in active filters** in Magento. **I use a rewrite for URLs**, are my filters as follows:

```
http://store.com/brand/foobrand/type/luxe/class/standard
```

In the Catalog page, I need to **know is that the filter page is active or not**.

Wherever I looked I thought almost always the same, but could not make it work:

```
$filters = array();
            $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

            foreach($appliedFilters as $filter) {
                $filters[] = $filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar();
            }

            if (!empty($filters)) {
                //filter active
            }
            if (empty($filters)) {
                //no
            }
```

Can anyone help me identify where you may be experiencing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check This one

```
  $filters = array();

  $filters = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();

  if (!empty($filters)) {
            //filter active
        }
        if (empty($filters)) {
            //no
        }
```

Comment: The response is null. The active filters is not detected. This code belongs to Observer.php.

Comment: @user2925795 please check this one http://magento.dingding.in/q/52992?lastactivity i think it will help you

Comment: This code doesnt work too. Could he be not identifying the rewrite as a filter?

Answer (score 1):

You can check like below:

```
$layer = Mage::registry('current_layer');
if ($layer) {
    return $layer;
}
```